# What is the Windows (and Linux?) equivalent of the Apple Java property apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz?

Tags: java, quartz-graphics, graphics2d

For my application drawing with Graphics2D increases in speed by about 5 times when I set

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz","true");
```

Is there a known equivalent for other platforms to take advantage of hardware acceleration?

Edit: I should point out that on Windows I believe it's not accelerated because it's running a lot slower than on my Mac despite the Windows machine having much much more powerful CPU and GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on OpenGL optimization:

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","true");
```

You can see Java's [full list of system properties for Java2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html) for more.

Note that I tried this, and it seemed to have no effect when I called `System.setProperty` on this.  In order to have any effect, I had to use -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true as a VM argument.  Even then, when I did it, it slowed down my application significantly.  I did most of my testing with our most custom Swing component, which did a lot of painting directly with the `Graphics2D` object.  It also interfered with our ability to probe the screen dimensions.  So I leave this property off.  You might find some other helpful properties in the link, however.  This testing was done under Linux.

Comment: Is there something you're specifically having a speed issue with?  Maybe you can do something to optimize your painting routines.

Comment: Optimising what I'm drawing (just a bunch of polygons) is a separate problem really. If I improve that then it'll still be way faster on OSX :)

Comment: Yeah, and the other hardware optimizations are going to vary greatly by application.  Some types of applications on some platforms may work better with OpenGL on, and other types might be better with it off.  The same is true of all of the other graphics options.